# Yum Transaction Check Error on install

Tags: centos, yum

`# yum install subversion subversion-devel neon neon-devel`

While trying to install some packages with `yum` – as shown above – I get the following error

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libpq.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.1.22-1.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/libpq.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.1.22-1.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/libpq.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.1.22-1.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/libpq.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.1.22-1.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/libpq.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.1.22-1.el5_5.1.i386 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1.x86_64
```

Now, the point is, if I try to run `yum-complete-transaction`, it wants to remove 130 packages(!). How can I get past this error without removing all those packages which spans from bash to openssl to yum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of yum would install both x86_64 and i386 packages by default. Try

```
# yum install subversion.x86_64 subversion-devel.x86_64 neon.x86_64 neon-devel.x86_64
```