# Error when trying to update postgresql-libs

Tags: postgresql, centos5, yum, update

When I do a `yum update` I get the following errors:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libecpg.so.6.1 from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libecpg_compat.so.3.1 from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so.3.1 from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5.2 from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-8.4.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-8.4.mo from install of postgresql-libs-8.4.10-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.i386
```

I have now idea as to how it may conflict since I have installed pgsql using `yum`.

But that's okay.

But I have no idea how to resolve these issues for me to be able to update pgsql libs.

There is a somewhat [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241313/yum-transaction-check-error-on-install), but that's regarding an install of i386 vs x86_64 versions.

So... how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

As requested the repolist of yum:

```
repo id           repo name                                             status
addons            CentOS-5 - Addons                                            0
base              CentOS-5 - Base                                        3,558+8
epel              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64           6,808
extras            CentOS-5 - Extras                                          269
ius               IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_6      149
kbs-CentOS-Extras CentOS.Karan.Org-EL5 - Stable                                0
kbs-CentOS-Misc   CentOS.Karan.Org-EL5 - Stable                                0
pgdg84            PostgreSQL 8.4 5 - x86_64                                  161
rpmforge          Red Hat Enterprise 5 - RPMforge.net - dag             10,899+1
updates           CentOS-5 - Updates                                      442+24
```

Comment: What repositories do you have: `yum repolist`?

Comment: @quanta: see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your installed version of postgresql is from yum.postgresql.org and that yum is attempting to update postgresql from the centos repo. If this is the case, have you tried adding an `exclude=postgresql*` line to the appropriate sections of your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS*.repo` files?

For example (from /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo):

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=postgresql*

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=postgresql*
```

**Update**
It looks like your `yum repolist` output confirms my hunch... You need to tell yum not to install/update/use the postgresql84 packages from the CentOS repos. Add the exclude statements to the base and updates sections of the CentOS-Base.repo file and you *should* be set.

Comment: I still get the same error after changing that.

Answer (score 1):

The conflict error often caused by a mixing up repositories. Try this:

```
# yum --disablerepo=pgdg84 install postgresql-libs
```

Comment: When I do: `yum --disablerepo=pgdg84 update` is states that there aren't any packages to be updated.

Comment: What is your final goal: update `postgresql-libs` or full update? Notice that `pgdg84` repository includes all the packages with `postgresql84` prefix and the installed package (8.4.10-1) is newer than `postgresql84-libs` which is pulled from `pgdg84` repo.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, although all the conflicts were against
`postgresql84-libs-8.4.6-1PGDG.rhel5.i386`

I only use x86_64 and simply removing the i386 libs worked for me. You could try this:

`yum remove postgresql84-libs-8.4.9-1.el5_7.1.i386`

There weren't any dependencies, so I was able to remove without problems, and after that yum update was able to complete without the error.